# typescript: значение по умолчанию для необязательного параметра

Tags: javascript, typescript, интерфейс, typescript-типы

подскажите, можно ли в интерфейса

```
interface IData {
    value1  : number,
    value2? : string
}
```

для необязательного параметра `value2` указать значение по умолчанию, если параметр не указан (по умолчанию он будет равен `undefined`

т.е. сделать что-то такое:

```
interface IData {
    value1  : number,
    value2? : string | 'default'
}
```

и если `value2` не указан, то он считается `'default'`

Comment: Мне кажется такого нельзя, а описать какое дефолтное значение можно через JSDoc.

Comment: JSDoc - это генератор документации, разве он воздействует на работу кода?

Comment: А что бы что? Просто интерфейса в рантайме нет и на что должно повлиять дефолтное значение непонятно. Покажите где и как вы это хотите использовать.

Comment: я хочу использовать с React так: - если есть `<Component value2="test" />`, то в `props` будет `props.value2: "test"`, а если `<Component />`, то в `props` будет `props.value2: "default"`, т.е. чтоб мне не проверять руками из серии `props.value2 || "default"`

Comment: Что мешает указать `function Component({value2 = "default"}) {}`?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jsg3gKGWQDc4AbAVwgEYAuZECgWwCNoBuQk8qgJgH56AZzBRQAc04BffPhgUQCMMAD2IZAGEVTAA5qI4ABS5ulGgBpTfZAF5kAcgAmEeBTJh7yKfQxY4ASnpiFWBHPC4ENSEVMggAOjIVcUNSM2pLVL44qAgdCCxDXn9-aVktXX0jE0yaenSrCF56exrPKRL8cr0QAzBjBrpkXi8OgHpR5AABMCEAWggADzyleagoFSgGFQHO7W7e-pqmhwB3FRO2jqA

Comment: @Oliver Patterson, а как это на компоненте react будет выглядеть?

Comment: Точно так же, но лучше покажите как вы делаете компоненты, для большего понимания.